# Tratando datas em scripts AWK

Tags: bash, timestamp, awk

**CONTEXTO:** Tenho um arquivo CSV do qual desejo extrair e processar algumas colunas. Percebi que o AWK seria a ferramenta perfeita para isso e tudo ia bem até que precisei lidar com *timestamps* - por exemplo *2008-07-31T21:42:52.667*

**PROBLEMA 1:** Eu preciso calcular a quantidade de dias que se passaram entre uma data base (digamos *2008-07-31*) e todos os *timestamps* na primeira coluna do arquivo de entrada.

**DETALHE:** Eu sei que eu consigo fazer operações de diferenças caso eu consiga usar o comando *date* do BASH, pois com o seguinte comando eu consigo a quantidade de segundos passados desde a data base do sistema de datas:

```
date -d"2008-07-31" +%s #RESULTADO: 1217473200s
```

Desta forma meu problema pode ser reduzido ao seguinte:

**PROBLEMA 2:** Como executar um comando bash de dentro do AWK?

Answer (score 3):

OK. Segue uma resposta para o **PROBLEMA 2**, o que já resolveu meu problema em geral, mas talvez tenha alguma outra solução mais legal.

Eu consigo executar um comando *bash* no GAWK usando a seguinte construção:

```
STRING_COMANDO | getline RESULTADO_VAR_NOME
```

Assim eu escrevi o seguinte script para pegar a primeira coluna de um arquivo - que possui um *timestamp* - e calcular a diferença da data base em segundos.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
  base_date="2008-07-31"
  #Comando para obter a quantidade de segundos da data base
  "date -d\""base_date"\" +%s" | getline first_day
  print "BASE: " base_date " -> " first_day
  #Variáveis utilizadas para evitar execuções BASH repitidas
  #Só ajudou pois sei que meu arquivo só tem datas em sequência crescente
  now_date="2008-07-31"
  now_day=first_day
}
{
  #Crio uma variável temp = [DATA,HORA]
  split($1,temp,"T")
  #Só invoco o BASH novamente se a data mudou
  if(temp[1] != now_date){
    now_date=temp[1]
    "date -d\""now_date"\" +%s" | getline now_day
  } 
  print now_date", " now_day", "now_day-first_day
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Em relação à aritmetica de datas apresento abaixo um hipotese dest vez com perl

Supondo que o ficheiro F tem o seguinte aspecto:

```
timestamp | legume | preço
2008-07-31T21:42:52.667 | batatas | 30
2008-08-31T21:42:52.667 | cebolas | 40
```

para demonstração vou juntar-lhe uma primeira coluna com os dias 
até ao natal

```
perl -MDate::Simple=date -pe '
  print /(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)(?=T)/ ? date("2016-12-25")-date($1) : "","|"' F
```

dá:

```
|timestamp | legume | preço
3069|2008-07-31T21:42:52.667 | batatas | 30
3038|2008-08-31T21:42:52.667 | cebolas | 40
```